# Not able to sort list in a certain way using OrderBy C# functionality

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, sql-order-by

*EDIT* - the correct result on the right (in the examples below) is how excel is doing the sort and what I am trying to accomplish with the OrderBy in C#.

I have the following OrderBy statement:

```
tempList.OrderBy(x => x.value);
```

and get the following results:

```
01P
41
90
```

but I need it to be the following instead:

```
41
90
01P
```

Is there a way using OrderBy to accomplish this type of sort? I have already tried adding all the variations of StringComparison.(type) but I could not ever get the sorting to work.

Any help is much appreciated!

More Examples below:

```
Sorted by OrderBy:                        What is needed instead:
```

Example 1)

```
35                                        7
7                                         35
```

Example 2)

```
44K                                       692
692                                       44K
```

Example 3)

```
0EP                                       629
0ET                                       0EP
692                                       0ET
```

Example 4)

```
10W                                       110
110                                       10W
```

Comment: my guess is that you are comparing the ASCII

Comment: What is the rule here? Items with no letters are smaller than those with letters?

Comment: the result on the left is how the custom sort from excel is sorting

Comment: Excel does all kinds of magic when the column type is "auto", it tests if the contents are *sort of numeric* and if so sorts numerically first. It's probably best to define your own rules and implement an `IComparer<string>` with the required behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I liked kkoyuncu's answer, it relies on two OrderBy's. You could eliminate that by having a Custom Comparer.

```
public class CustomComparer : IComparer<string>
{
   public int Compare(string stringA, string stringB)
    {
        var isValueAInt = int.TryParse(stringA, out var valueA);
        var isValueBInt = int.TryParse(stringB, out var valueB);

        if(isValueAInt && isValueBInt)
        {
            return valueA - valueB;
        }
        else if(isValueAInt && !isValueBInt)
        {
            return-1;
        }
        else if(!isValueAInt && isValueBInt)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return String.Compare(stringA,stringB);

    }
}
```

Now your code would look like,

```
string[] myArray = { "35", "7","110","10W","0EP","0ET","692"};
var comparer = new CustomComparer();
var result = myArray.OrderBy(a=>a,comparer);
```

Output

```
7 
35 
110 
692 
0EP 
0ET 
10W
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a numeric sort before. Try like below:

```
string[] myArray = { "0EP", "0ET", "692" };

var result = myArray.OrderBy(a => !int.TryParse(a, out var _)).ThenBy(a => a).ToList();
```